# LogoLists inserts commas, NetLogo -> Java -> NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm passing a NetLogo list from NetLogo to Java (to an extension) and then sending it back to NetLogo again where I want to use it as a parameter to another procedure. But when I send it back to NetLogo, the Java representation of the LogoList seems to have changed it so that it contains commas, i.e.

`[0 0]` becomes `[0, 0]` which makes NetLogo complain when I then pass it on. (It says that it expected a constant.)

When I retrieve the list from the arguments in the ExtensionCode, I use the args[0].getList().

e: I pass it back to NetLogo as a string, by the way. I pretty much need to do this because I am doing this as part of an iterative string-building procedure. I hope there's still a way to do this.

Does this make sense? Am I doing something wrong? I assume I can turn the LogoList into an iterator, and then build a new LogoList with a LogoListBuilder, but I was wondering if there might be a better way: What should I do to send the LogoList back to NetLogo without commas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a LogoList (or any other NetLogo value) to a string, don't use `.toString`; that's only suitable for debugging. Calling `org.nlogo.api.Dump.logoObject` on the LogoList will produce the Logo-style representation instead of the Java-style representation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this can add something to @Seth reply, but if you also need to build the list in Java, you can also use within a DefaultReporter:

```
LogoListBuilder newList = new LogoListBuilder();
// do your stuff... then:
return newList.toLogoList();
```

in this way, the list is in the correct format when you process it in NetLogo.

Comment: Yeah, I actually iterated over my data and built a LogoListBuilder, and then used the toLogoList() method to send it back. Fortunately Seth's method made that a lot easier. :)